# Why am I getting OleDBException "No value given for one or more required parameters?"

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oledb

This is my code:

```
command.CommandText = 
   "SELECT DISTINCT B.* FROM BlankFormSubmissions B, Actions A WHERE B.FormName = " + 
   GenericRoutines.SqlFmt(form.Name) + 
   " AND B.ProcessName = A.ProcessName AND B.ActionName = A.ActionName" +
   " ORDER BY B.ID";

OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

The SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.* 
FROM BlankFormSubmissions B, Actions A 
WHERE B.FormName = 'FindingNemo' 
  AND B.ProcessName = A.ProcessName 
  AND B.ActionName = A.ActionName 
ORDER BY B.ID
```

Comment: Use **parametrized** queries instead of concatenating together your SQL statements - helps [avoid SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).....

Comment: Hi, how does it work if you only use the command text: "SELECT DISTINCT B.* FROM BlankFormSubmissions B, Actions A" ?

Comment: And while you're at it - try to use the newer, standardized ANSI JOIN syntax with the `INNER JOIN .... ON .....` clauses - helps avoid unwanted cartesian products and is just so much clearer to read and understand...

Comment: Thanks guys, but this code is perfectly protected against any attacks by the method you don't see the implementation of, GenericRoutines.SqlFmt(...)

Comment: @Lost Hobbit - if that's true, I'd *love* to see SqlFmt.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'll second that!

Comment: public static string SqlFmt(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return "NULL";
            return "'" + value.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
        }

Comment: Here's a site you may like: http://thedailywtf.com/  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found by running the SQL within Access, that I was actually just referencing a column (FormName) which did not exist in the Access table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote any strings you're passing into your query. Try:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT B.* FROM BlankFormSubmissions B, Actions A WHERE B.FormName = '" + 
        GenericRoutines.SqlFmt(form.Name) + "' AND B.ProcessName = A.ProcessName AND B.ActionName = A.ActionName" +
        " ORDER BY B.ID";
```

Its easier (once you get over the v. minor learning curve involved) and better (neater, more secure) to use a *Parameterised query* or *Stored procedure* to do this sort of thing.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, but my method SqlFmt() adds the quotes for me.

Comment: An old adage from computing, summarised by the acronym 'PSIGSO'  - 'Put Sh1t in, Get Sh1t Out'. Perhaps posting a more complete code sample would have got you more useful answers ;-)

Glad you've sorted it.

Comment: I thought the fact that I posted the SQL that my code generated would have been enough... oh well.

Comment: Without the table definitions EVERYTHING is an error as the IDE can't find any of your referenced db objects. This is StackOverflow, not a direct line to God Almighty ;-)